# python 3 pandas read_sql converts string query to byte only on linux

Tags: python, sql, linux, pandas

I have a Python 3.5 script that works perfectly on Windows. Now I've tried it on Linux and I got the following error:

```
TypeError: The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query.
```

The script is logging the SQL queries so I see that the query is really a byte (b'my sql query'). On Windows the query does not converted into byte. On Linux, it does. Why? I use parameterized SQL queries, and if I use `.decode('utf-8')` I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

So my SQL query is a string...
The main part of my script is:

```
df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, sql_engine)
```

I use pandas 0.17.1

Thanky for help!

---

**Update:**
On Linux, the output of SqlAlchemy logging is:

```
2015-12-03 02:23:44 PM | INFO | b'SELECT 1;'
2015-12-03 02:23:44 PM | INFO | ()
2015-12-03 02:23:44 PM | INFO | ROLLBACK
```

On Windows exactly the same script produces the following SqlAlchemy logging:

```
2015-12-03 02:46:25 PM | INFO | SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%%'
2015-12-03 02:46:25 PM | INFO | ()
2015-12-03 02:46:25 PM | INFO | SELECT 1;
2015-12-03 02:46:26 PM | INFO | ()
```

Type of my `sql_query` SQL query is `<class 'str'>`

Here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<my script file>.py", line <xyz>, in get_df_from_dwh
    df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, sql_engine)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 513, in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1181, in read_query
    result = self.execute(*args)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1072, in execute
    return self.connectable.execute(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1991, in execute
    return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 906, in execute
    return self._execute_text(object, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1054, in _execute_text
    statement, parameters
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1146, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1344, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1139, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 450, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
TypeError: The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query.
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? Eg the full error traceback, output in the console of `sql_query` and `type(sql_query)`

Comment: Thanks for reply, I updated the question...

Comment: Which version of sqlalchemy are you using?

Comment: 1.0.9 on both Windows & Linux

Comment: You said you are using a parameterized SQL string, how are you providing the parameters then in `pd.read_sql(sql_query, sql_engine)`?

Comment: `sql_query = "SELECT 1;"` Instead one could use `pd.read_sql("SELECT 1;", sql_engine)` but [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698664/the-first-argument-to-execute-must-be-a-string-or-unicode-query) is suggested to avoid this. Oh, yes, in the sample query I do not use parameters, but the error occures with this simple query as well..