# python 3 sqlalchemy mysql pyodbc dialect error

Tags: python, linux, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I had a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067145/python-3-pandas-read-sql-converts-string-query-to-byte-only-on-linux#) last week. I use SqlAlchemy and pyodbc on Windows and on Linux. On Windows everything works perfectly, on Linux, I get errors.

Now I've debugged the SqlAlchemy and pandas source code with `pdb`. I found that `/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/pyodbc.py` sets `supports_unicode_statements = False`. If I set it to `True` then I won't get byte sql queries in sqlalchemy logging (see details in the link below). So I get this:

```
2015-12-09 14:06:03,237 | INFO |   5528 - SELECT 1;
2015-12-09 14:06:03,237 | INFO |   5528 - ()
2015-12-09 14:06:03,241 | INFO |   5528 - ROLLBACK
```

But I get an other error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY000', '[HY000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]
Driver returned SQL_ERROR or SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO but no error reporting API found (0) 
(SQLExecDirectW)') [SQL: 'SELECT 1;']
```

Any idea why I get this? If I use `mssql+pyodbc` dialect insted `mysql+pyodbc` then I get the same error :(

Thanks for help!